# How to use s3cmd multithreaded?

Tags: amazon-web-services, multithreading, download, s3cmd

Our goal is to download about 5 millions of tiny files from AWS to CentOS server. We found s3cmd utility and it was very good for almost all things. Except downloading, because it is only supports one thread :( which follow to 60 days of downloading, which is just crazy!

Is there any new version of s3cmd or another way to download all files in multithread mode?

Comment: Aren't you limited in downloading by your internet connection?

Comment: @JeanLogeart Yes, I am, but one-thread got max 500 kBps, but my internet can handle max 10 Mbps. I've tested on another machine (Windows) with S3Browser in multithreaded mode, and it make 4-5 Mbps speed in 40 threads. But I need the same in CentOS.

Comment: Did you try opening multiple terminals?

Comment: @JeanLogeart I have thinked about it. But how will it work on the same files? Because it is not such simple task to divide whole bucket to parts. Lets say this is a solution, but I will use it only in worst case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have open s4cmd for myself, awesome tool. And yes, it supports multithreading.